# How to create a variable based on a time period grouped on id number

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe

```
idnr <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7)
labvalue <- c(100, 80, 75, 70, 50, 60, 55, 200, 180, 165, 160, 150, 170, 175, 300, 280, 260, 250, 255, 400, 380, 360, 350, 355, 500, 480, 460)
labdate <- as.Date(c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-01-07", 
                    "2022-01-08", "2022-01-09", "2022-01-10", "2022-01-11", "2022-01-12", "2022-01-13", "2022-01-14", 
                    "2022-01-15", "2022-01-16", "2022-01-17", "2022-01-18", "2022-01-19", "2022-01-20", "2022-01-21", 
                    "2022-01-22", "2022-01-23", "2022-01-24", "2022-01-25", "2022-01-26", "2022-01-27"))

data <- data.frame(idnr, labvalue, labdate)
```

I would like to create a variable for each idnr indicating if the unique idnr have had a drop in lab value of 40 or more and within 2 days. To clarify, if a unique idnr has a lab value of 200, i want to check if there is any lab values taken after the date of lab value 200 but within 48 hours that is 160 or less.

Preferably I would like it to work if the dates had time stamps as well. I understand that I probably need to do a for loop but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a helper function to check each row for drops within 2 days, then apply to dates and values using `purrr::map2_lgl()`, grouped by `idnr`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

has_drop <- function(cur_date, cur_value, all_dates, all_values) {
  days_diff <- as.numeric(all_dates - cur_date, unit = "days")
  vals_2day <- all_values[between(days_diff, 0, 2)]
  any(vals_2day - cur_value <= -40)
}

data %>% 
  group_by(idnr) %>% 
  summarize(
    drop = any(map2_lgl(
      labdate, 
      labvalue, 
      \(d, v) has_drop(d, v, labdate, labvalue)
    ))
  )
```

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 2
   idnr drop 
  <dbl> <lgl>
1     1 FALSE
2     2 FALSE
3     5 TRUE 
4     6 TRUE 
5     7 TRUE
```

To get the dates of values with drops within 2 days, use `filter()` instead of `summarize`():

```r
data %>% 
  group_by(idnr) %>% 
  filter(map2_lgl(
    labdate, 
    labvalue, 
    \(d, v) has_drop(d, v, labdate, labvalue)
  )) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 3
   idnr labvalue labdate   
  <dbl>    <dbl> <date>    
1     5      300 2022-01-15
2     6      400 2022-01-20
3     7      500 2022-01-25
```

The same code should work for POSIXct timestamps.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! How would I modify the code if I also wanted the date of the lab value that had the decrease of 40 or more?

Comment: Works awesome but for the wrong date, I would like the date of the lower lab value. Is this doable?

Comment: Yes, you can actually get that by flipping the computations in the function from `all_dates - cur_date` to `cur_date - all_dates`, and from `vals_2day - cur_value` to `cur_value - vals_2day`, leaving everything else as is.